# Бот должен отвечать пользователю по message_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Создаю бота для связи между группой и пользователями. В бота отправляют простое смс и оно приходит в группу(от бота). Человек в группе отвечает на это сообщение командой по типу /answer и бот отправляет сообщение(которое прописано в команде /answer) пользователю, который отправил простое смс.

Пример реализации

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['answer'])# команда ответа
def answer_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ответ")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    message.chat.id2 = '-123' #id группы
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id2, message.text)
```

Но суть в том, что сообщения идут просто пользователю группы, который написал в ней /answer

Comment: как вы используете команду `/answer` в группе? в плане написания, а не функционала.

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет [эта](https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/chapter7) статья.